# jquery, once form submit has complete

Tags: jquery

Mornin all. I was wondering if someone could tell me how i go about activating a function in jquery once a form submit to an iframe has completed?

Regards Phil

Comment: Where's JS is executed, in the page containing the iFrame?

Comment: no parent, i want to take result out of iframe and put in parent and then remove iframe; like it was never there.

Comment: Is your iframe pulling from the domain other than the parent page? If so - you won't be able to access the DOM

Comment: Im not being ignorant to your answers the answers gave havn't helpped me im still in the same boat. If i recieve an answer or a comment that leads to an answer i will click the tick.

Answer (score 1):

The form submission can return a javascript block which can call a function in the parent document; eg:

```
<html><script language="javascript">
  window.parent.document.doSomething();
</script></html>
```

and inside the `doSomething()` function you call your jQuery code.